# python redis pubsub blocking

Tags: python, redis-py

```
import redis
import threading

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, r, channel):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.redis = r
        self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
        self.pubsub.subscribe(channel)

def run(self):
    for item in self.pubsub.listen():
        # do stuff
        pass
```

in the above code how I do stop the thread?

Below I have an example code to show you what I would like:

```
class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, r, channel):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.redis = r
         self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
         self.pubsub.subscribe(channel)
         self.stop = False

    def run(self):
        while not stop:
            # get item from channel
```

So when the attribute stop == True the thread will exit the loop and will finish.
Is that possible? If it is not what are the alternatives?

Comment: Here is a non-blocking example with ioloop termination once message has been received - https://github.com/abhinavsingh/async_pubsub/blob/master/examples/redis_subscribe.py#L27

Answer (score 4):

There is a useful gist that shows how to pass in a command that will break the loop and unsubscribe.  This may be useful to see how you could do it in other ways.

```
for item in self.pubsub.listen():
    if item['data'] == "KILL":
        self.pubsub.unsubscribe()
        print self, "unsubscribed and finished"
        break
    else:
        self.work(item)
```

You can see the example code here:

- https://gist.github.com/jobliz/2596594